# copy button should patch when textbox value is entered and attached code

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, powerapp, powerapps-canvas, formula

Below is my code when I click copy button

```
Set(varrecord,Gallery2.Selected);
ForAll(
    Filter(
        Gallery2.AllItems,
        Checkbox1.Value 
    ),
    Patch(
       Roster, 
       Defaults(Roster),
       {
                    
           Title:varrecord.Title,
           Grade:varrecord.VacancyGrade, 
//how to make this required field in code and only if the value is entered it should patch          
           VacancyID: Value(TextInput1.Text),
    }
);
);
UpdateContext({locResetCheckbox:true});
Reset(TextInput1);
UpdateContext({locResetCheckbox:false});
```

[image]

Comment: What is the issue here? Is above formula giving any error or is it not creating items in the list?

Comment: when i click copy button its getting patching but issue is i want to make my textbox required field so it should prompt for error is textbox is empty and after textbox value entered it should patch,but in my code its patching but i am not sure how to make the textbox as required field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use formula like below in OnSelect property of your button control:

```
If(
    IsBlank(TextInput1.Text), 
    Notify("Text box is empty, please enter valid Vacancy ID", Error), 
    //Your current code
)
```

Add your current code in above formula properly.

Comment: Working as expected and Thanks a lot for your quick solutions in resolving issue. Fantastic support